# Copy the contents of a JPanel onto a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage

On the first time through, I insert `BufferedImage`s from a list onto my `JPanel` from my extended class:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (controlWhichImage == 1){
        for (BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g.drawImage(eachImage, 0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
        }

        if (intx >= this.getWidth() || inty >= this.getHeight()){
            inty = 0;
        }
```

The next time I want to copy the contents of the `JPanel` to a `BufferedImage`:

```
public void recordImage(){
    controlWhichImage = 2;
    this.createdImage = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Image halfWay = this.createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    //now cast it from Image to bufferedImage
    this.createdImage = (BufferedImage) halfWay;
}
```

And then, take the modified `BufferedImage` and draw it back onto the `JPanel`:

```
if (controlWhichImage == 2){
    g.drawImage(this.createdImage,0,inty,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null);
}
```

This second time I get a blank panel.

I hope this is clear, any help gratefully received.

Sorry for my poor explanation. I will try to make myself clearer.

On each iteration the user is able to draw on the image in the Jpanel.

What I want to do is copy the user altered jpanel into a buffered image which will then be in the Jpanel to be edited again by the user.

This continues until the user selects print.

So apart from the code that I have put here are the controls for drawing by the user, at the moment I am struggling with putting the initial updated image from the original Jpanel into a bufferedImage and then back to the JPanel. 
Hope this makes it somewhat clearer

Comment: Please clarify, firstly by telling us what behavior/effect you're trying to achieve? What user experience are you trying to achieve? Next, if you can create and post a valid [mcve], that would help ***greatly***. This would be asking a bit of work of you, but it would be worthwhile in that we would be able to more fully understand your code and your problem. Please check out the [mcve] link for the details.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I was trying to keep it as simple as I could.

Comment: After the first time through the I draw rectangles on the buffered images in the JPanel. Then on the second time I am trying to display the altered images for more editing. I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Again, I'm trying to get you to explain this away from programming jargon and instead from the point of view of the user. So, correct me if I'm wrong -- you want to display an image to the user, allow the user to be able to edit it somehow, and then save the image with user-generated changes, and be able to generate it again later if needed -- correct? Are you trying to save the image to disk? To variable? How? And again, I strongly urge you to create and post a valid [mcve] for us.

Comment: Please comment back to me if you decide to act on my suggestions above.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had tried to take your suggestions onboard by  editing my original question is that not any good?

Comment: Well, I created as best an answer as I could based on the information you've given. if it answers your question, great, if not, then you really want to post that [mcve].

Comment: It is not safe to cast the object returned by Component.createImage to a BufferedImage.  Just because it's returning a BufferedImage right now doesn't mean future Java versions will, or that other OSes will.

Answer (score 1):

To draw to a BufferedImage, you would do something similar to what you already do in your paintComponent method, but with your BufferedImage. Perhaps a method like:

```
// imgW and imgH are the width and height of the desired ultimate image
public BufferedImage combineImages(List<BufferedImage> docList, int imgW, int imgH) {
    // first create the main image that you want to draw to
    BufferedImage mainImg = new BufferedImage(imgW, imgH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // get its Graphics context
    Graphics g = mainImage.getGraphics();

    int intx = 0;
    int inty = 0;

    // draw your List of images onto this main image however you want to do this
    for (BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g.drawImage(eachImage, 0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
        }
    }

    // anything else that you need to do

    g.dispose(); // dispose of this graphics context to save resources

    return mainImg;
}
```

You could then store the image returned into a varaible and then draw it in your JPanel if desired, or write it to disk.

If this doesn't answer your question, then again you'll want to tell more and show us your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).