# How do I copy contents of JPanel to BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have two BufferedImages from a list(this.docList). In my paintComponent method I draw them to the JPanel and at the same time draw them on 'this.createdImage.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.createdImage = newBufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); Graphics g2 = this.createdImage.getGraphics();
    if (controlWhichImage == 1){
        for(BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g2.drawImage(eachImage,0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            g.drawImage(eachImage, 0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
            }

        if (intx >= this.getWidth() || inty >= this.getHeight()){
            inty = 0;
        }
```

My problem is when I go to use createdImage all I get is a blank panel.

```
if (controlWhichImage == 2){
     g.drawImage(this.createdImage,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null);
}
```

Comment: Don't perform expensive operations like creating a BufferedImage inside a paint method.  paintComponent (and all paint methods) can be called several times per second!

Comment: Duplicate of [*Copy the contents of a JPanel onto a BufferedImage*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35363892/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Each time `paintComponent` is called, you create a new instance of `BufferedImage`, if `controlWhichImage` is `1` it paints the images to the `BufferedImage`, if it's `2` it paints, well nothing.

Basically your code is basically operating like...

```
Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.createdImage = newBufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
    Graphics g2 = this.createdImage.getGraphics();
    if (controlWhichImage == 1){
        for(BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g2.drawImage(eachImage,0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            g.drawImage(eachImage, 0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,null);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
        }

        if (intx >= this.getWidth() || inty >= this.getHeight()){
            inty = 0;
        }
    } else if (controlWhichImage == 2){
         g.drawImage(this.createdImage,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null);
    }
```

What you should only be creating an instance of `createdImaeg` when `controlWhichImage` is `1`

```
Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (controlWhichImage == 1){
        this.createdImage = newBufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        Graphics g2 = this.createdImage.getGraphics();
        for(BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g2.drawImage(eachImage,0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,this);
            g.drawImage(eachImage, 0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,this);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
        }

        if (intx >= this.getWidth() || inty >= this.getHeight()){
            inty = 0;
        }
        g2.dispose(); // This is kind of important...
    } else if (controlWhichImage == 2){
         g.drawImage(this.createdImage,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
    }
```

or when `createdImage` is null...

```
Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (createdImage == null){
        this.createdImage = newBufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        Graphics g2 = this.createdImage.getGraphics();
        for(BufferedImage eachImage : docList){
            g2.drawImage(eachImage,0,inty,imageWidth,imageHeight,this);
            intx += eachImage.getWidth();
            inty += eachImage.getHeight() * zoomAdd;
        }

        if (intx >= this.getWidth() || inty >= this.getHeight()){
            inty = 0;
        }
        g2.dispose(); // This is kind of important...
    }
    g.drawImage(this.createdImage,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
```

Comment: Ok I have changed it to:

Comment: if (createdImage == null){
            this.createdImage = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }

Comment: but on 2 it is still blank. But thank you for your reply

Comment: Well since you've chosen not to provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem every thing else is purly guess work

Comment: Sorry,I am trying to keep it as simple as possiblle. It is not that I did not want to supply a runnable example, it just how and then to keep it as simple.

Comment: Then all it leaves us is guess work